# Object literal in filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I have my filter configured like this,and I need to pass the filter object in a dinamic way.

```
filter: function ( response ) {
    return $.map(response,function (object) {                   
        return {
            value: object.descricaoMunicipio,
            municipioId: object.municipioId,
            descricaoMunicipio: object.descricaoMunicipio,
            id: object.municipioId
        };
    });     
}
```

I need to pass the return in a generic way,like this:Is it possible?

```
var fnc = {
    value: object.uf.descricaoUf,
    municipioId: object.municipioId,
    descricaoMunicipio: object.uf.descricaoUf,
    id: object.municipioId
}


filter: function ( response ) {
    return $.map(response,function (object) {
        return {
            eval(fnc)
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a named that does what you want:

```
var fnc = function(object) {
    return {
        value: object.uf.descricaoUf,
        municipioId: object.municipioId,
        descricaoMunicipio: object.uf.descricaoUf,
        id: object.municipioId
    };
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
filter: function(response) {
    return $.map(response, function (object) {
        return fnc(object);
    });
}
```

Or you can just write:

```
filter: function(response) {
    return $.map(response, fnc);
}
```